# jQuery.data() does not work in IE11 on first page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

Hello to all the community.

First of all I'd like to thank everyone for hundreds of great answers I found here in the past. It is probably the first time I don't find one.

I discovered today that my **IE11 does not digest $.data() when a page is first opened** in its tab. Here's the test code (http://dmit.izihost.com/temp/test_IE11_jQuery.htm):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="fr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(function(){

    $('#do').data('data1', '1');

    $('#do').html($('#do').html() + '<br>Document Ready: ' + 
        $('#do').data('data1') + 
        " - Here the data is still present"
    );

});

$(window).load(function(){

    $('#do').html($('#do').html() + '<br>Window Load: ' + 
        $('#do').data('data1') +
        " - Here in IE11 the data is lost when page is opened for the first time; but present after reloading (F5, Ctrl+F5 etc.) in the same browser tab");

});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="do"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Try to open it with IE11 (if you test locally, drag-drop the file into the browser rather than double-click), then refresh the page, then open it again in another tab/instance.

I find nothing of the sort in Google. Can someone please shed the light on this issue? It seems to be rather ugly, unless it's a temporary bug.

Good day!

D

P.S. IE version: *11.0.9600.16518*

Comment: Bugs should be submitted to http://bugs.jquery.com/

Comment: I can't reproduce this in IE11.

Comment: A way that might happen would be if the "load" handler ran before the "ready" handler. Relying on ordering between "ready" and "load" handlers seems like a bad code smell to me anyway, though I would have guessed that jQuery tries pretty hard to make sure "ready" fires before "load".

Comment: It's not about load vs ready, I first discovered this issue in an onclick handler, that happens 30 seconds after document.ready.

Comment: @user3365907 Can you consistently reproduce the issue with that setup?

Comment: I updated the code of the link, to wait 1 second before showing the missing data. I reproduce it consistently on the FIRST opening of the page online in IE11 (see exact version in P.S.) It should show: .... Window Load: undefined - ....

Comment: Is this one failing for you? http://jsfiddle.net/dmethvin/yWr7M/

Comment: No, jsfiddle version works correctly (unlike the link). What worries me is that the behavior is very unstable, like for the link I gave it happens on first load but not after Ctrl+F5. I also wonder if it happens only in Win8. Did anyone reproduce this issue somewhere? (I came upon it as several users with IE11 reported a problem, so I doubt it's just me)

Comment: Update: apparently **using Options->Advanced->Reinitalize to restore default IE parameters removes the problem**, on my machine and for several users who reported this issue. The problem is, my IE was "brand new" and I did no modifications to parameters; which means that a lot of users are concerned. I still hope for someone to shed the light on this issue..